# Python best way to check for existing key

Tags: python

Which is the more efficient/faster/better way to check if a key exists?

```
if 'subject' in request.POST:
    subject = request.POST['subject']
else:
    // handle error
```

OR

```
try:
    subject = request.POST['subject']
except KeyError:
    // handle error
```

Comment: Which of "efficient", "faster", and "better" do you really care about, and what definition of "efficient" and "better" do you have in mind?

Comment: I guess I meant which is the best coding practice.

In this particular situation, if 'subject' is not is POST, than it is an error, there is no default value that should be there.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The latter (`try/except`) form is generally the better form.

`try` blocks are very cheap but catching an exception can be more expensive. A containment check on a dict tends to be cheap, but not cheaper than nothing. I suspect there will be a balance of efficiency depending on how often `'subject'` is really there. However, **this doesn't matter**, since premature optimization is useless, distracting, wasteful, and ineffective. You would go with the better solution.

If the code would actually be of the form

```
if 'subject' in request.POST:
    subject = request.POST['subject']
else:
    subject = some_default
```

then what you actually want is `request.POST.get('subject', some_default)`.

Answer (score 6):

I use .get() method — it is preferable method.

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jul 22 2009, 15:33:10)
[GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> def f1(key, d):
...   if key in d:
...     return d[key]
...   else:
...     return "default"
...
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (key)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 JUMP_IF_FALSE           12 (to 24)
             12 POP_TOP

  3          13 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (key)
             19 BINARY_SUBSCR
             20 RETURN_VALUE
             21 JUMP_FORWARD             5 (to 29)
        >>   24 POP_TOP

  5          25 LOAD_CONST               1 ('default')
             28 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def f2(key, d):
...   return d.get(key, "default")
...
>>> dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (get)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (key)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 ('default')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def f3(key, d):
...   try:
...     return d[key]
...   except KeyError:
...     return "default"
...
>>> dis.dis(f3)
  2           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            12 (to 15)

  3           3 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (key)
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 RETURN_VALUE
             11 POP_BLOCK
             12 JUMP_FORWARD            23 (to 38)

  4     >>   15 DUP_TOP
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (KeyError)
             19 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             22 JUMP_IF_FALSE           11 (to 36)
             25 POP_TOP
             26 POP_TOP
             27 POP_TOP
             28 POP_TOP

  5          29 LOAD_CONST               1 ('default')
             32 RETURN_VALUE
             33 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 38)
        >>   36 POP_TOP
             37 END_FINALLY
        >>   38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             41 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Last time I checked, the first one is a few nanoseconds faster.  But most phythonistas seem to favor the second one.

I think I'm not the only one that want to reserve exceptions for exceptional behavior, so I try to use the first one, reserving the second one when it's invalid not to have the key

Comment: This *is* an exceptional circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

The second will fail with `collections.defaultdict`, and the exception will cause a small performance bump. Other than there there is no real difference between the two.

Comment: It's technically true that the second method will fail with `collections.defaultdict`, but more fundamentally, *this is why* `collections.defaultdict` *exists*.

Answer (score 1):

```
subject = request.POST.get("subject")
if subject is None:
   ...
```

:)

Comment: And if the value associated with `"subject"` *is* `None`?

Comment: This is less readable than either of the solutions in the original post. It replaces exceptions with return value checking and is less direct than a containment check, and it has a bug if `request.Post['subject']` already is `None`.

Comment: @Jon-Eric: I presume it can't be because all HTTP posted values are strings.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (which asked about efficiency), but it's also a valid approach for checking dict() values without handling a `KeyError`. What's missed in other comments here is sometimes all that matters is if the return value is available or not.

Comment: I think my `.get()` approach is the most effective (see analysis from @Aleksa) - I have only one dict lookup and no exception processing. Other answers have two dict lookups or an exception processing.

Comment: Of course if you need to handle `None` value you can change the code a bit:

subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'default value')

Or


missing = object();
subject = request.POST.get('subject', missing);
if subject is not missing:
    ...

Yes, this last version is a bit tricky and less readable. But if you want the most effective code...

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on whether 'subject' not being in POST is actually an exception.  If it is not supposed to happen but you are just being extra careful, then your second method would I assume be more efficient and quicker.  However if you are using the check to do 1 thing or another then it is not appropriate to use an exception.  From the look of your code, I would go with your second option.

Comment: It is certainly an exceptional circumstance (even if it occurs 90% of the time!).

Comment: How could something that occurs 90% of the time be exceptional?

Comment: All other cases (key does exist) are in a different category than it.

Comment: thats not an exception thats a condition.

Answer (score 1):

I too like get() you can also specify a default value (other than none) in case that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`dict` and many dict-like objects (including Django's `HttpRequest` you seem to be using) allow passing default value to `get()`:

```
subject = request.POST.get('subject', '[some_default_subject]')
```

This is preferrable method as it is the shortest and most transparent about your intentions.